# Oracle 11g: copying a column from one table to another adding an sequence ID. Dropping a sequence

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I would like to copy the column values from one table to another doing something like (doesn't work):

```
create sequence INSTITUTION_SEQ
minvalue 1
maxvalue 999999999999999999999
start with 1
increment by 1
cache 20;

INSERT INTO INSTITUTION 
(ID, NAME)
VALUES(
INSTITUTION_SEQ.nextval, 
SELECT DISTINCT ACB_BANK_NAME FROM LUP ORDER BY ACB_BANK_NAME
);
```

**Questions**

1. What is the correct SQL query to launch in order to get the expected result ?
2. How can the sequence be dropped at the end of the script ? Tried `DROP INSTITUTION_SEQ` but cause an `ORA-00950: invalid DROP option`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of create/use/drop a sequence you can get a sequential value using:

```
INSERT INTO INSTITUTION (ID, NAME)
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ACB_BANK_NAME), ACB_BANK_NAME 
FROM
 ( -- DISTINCT is processed after ROW_NUMBER
   SELECT DISTINCT ACB_BANK_NAME FROM LUP
 ) dt;

INSERT INTO INSTITUTION (ID, NAME)
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ACB_BANK_NAME), ACB_BANK_NAME 
FROM LUP
GROUP BY ACB_BANK_NAME; -- GROUP BY is processed before ROW_NUMBER
```

Comment: Thanks both work. Up voted! Marked the previous answer as answered despite this one work perfectly, as both are correct but the previous one was answered first. Just wondering if one approach is any better than the other, as you get more up vote ?

Comment: @HeyStackExchange - actually this answer beat mine by a few seconds *8-) I've left mine there because it's slightly different, despite being the same idea. You should test both (or all three) if you're concerned about the performance difference

Comment: @AlexPoole Thank for your fair-play. Got to be myself. So marked answered this one as couldn't choose ;) Thanks a lot both

Comment: ROW_NUMBER is generic while ROWNUM is Oracle specific (but should be more efficient, especially when there's no order by needed)

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to create and drop a sequence, you can use `rownum` or an analytic function:

```
INSERT INTO INSTITUTION (ID, NAME)
SELECT rownum, ACB_BANK_NAME
FROM (
  SELECT DISTINCT ACB_BANK_NAME FROM LUP ORDER BY ACB_BANK_NAME
);
```